# How to reference enum type in entity sql

Tags: entity-framework-6, ef-database-first, entity-sql

I have the following (simplified) Entity SQL query:

```
SELECT VALUE a
FROM Customers AS a
WHERE a.Status NOT IN { 2, 3 }
```

The `Status` property is an enumeration type, call it `CustomerStatus`. The enumeration is defined in the EDMX file.

As it is, this query doesn't work, throwing an exception to the effect that CustomerStatus is incompatible with Int32 (its underlying type *is* int). However, I couldn't find a way to define a list of CustomerStatus values for the `IN {}` clause, no matter what namespace I prefixed to the enumeration name. For example,

```
SELECT VALUE a
FROM Customers AS a
WHERE a.Status NOT IN { MyModelEntities.CustomerStatus.Reject, MyModelEntities.CustomerStatus.Accept }
```

did not work, throwing an exception saying it could not find MyModelEntities.CustomerStatus in the container, or some such.

Eventually I resorted to casting the `Status` to int, such as

```
SELECT VALUE a
FROM Customers AS a
WHERE CAST(a.Status AS System.Int32) NOT IN { 2, 3 }
```

but I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Can't you just cast the enum to (int) before the query is sent?

Comment: @DanielLorenz what do you mean? As you can see in the last query, eventually that's what I did.

Comment: Are you building the SQL yourself or are you using a DbSet?  If you build the SQL yourself, you have to use an int as the database doesn't have a concept of an enum.  EF translates that to an int.

Comment: @DanielLorenz it's statically defined. Entity SQL is executed against the conceptual model, not against the database directly. EF translates it to T-SQL later in the pipeline. So while the database has no concept of enums, EF does. So I thought I could use them in eSQL just as I can use them in LINQ to Entities.

Comment: What version of EF are you using?  It should automatically convert this for you in EF 6+.  Not sure about 5, but 4 you have to manually convert to int.

Comment: @DanielLorenz it's EF6. Again, this is **Entity SQL**, not **T-SQL**. It seems like EF is unable to recognize the enum type I'm referring to in the query, let alone convert it to int.

Answer (score 0):

Oooh, you are writing Entity SQL directly.  I see...  Any reason you aren't using DbSet instead of writing Entity SQL by hand?  Could always do

```
var statuses = new [] { Status.A, Status.B };
var query = context.SomeTable.Where(a => !statuses.Contains(a.Status)).ToList();
```

Comment: The reason is the query is actually generated dynamically with `String.Format`, replacing the selected column from the entity (the actual query actually selects a navigation property from `a`) and modifies the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Hmm, I don't really see anything here that would warrant using dynamic SQL, really.  You can't do ctx.Customers.Where(a => statuses..).Select(a => a.Value).ToList() ?

Comment: The actual query is more complicated. I may select `a.ValueA` or `a.ValueB`, and in addition to the status list, the `WHERE` clause has additional dynamic conditions. Something like `String.Format("SELECT VALUE a.{0} FROM Customers AS a
WHERE CAST(a.Status AS System.Int32) NOT IN {{ 2, 3 }} AND a.{1} IS NOT NULL", selectedProperty, filterProperty)`